# What is the difference between [dependencies] and [dependencies.<NAME>] in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, toml

I have been looking at the Cargo.toml files for the substrate-node-template and noticed they have some dependencies listed like this:

```toml
[dependencies.grandpa]
package = 'sc-finality-grandpa'
version = '0.8.0-alpha.5'
```

What is the difference between that and listing under `[dependencies]` like:

```toml
[dependencies]
sc-finality-grandpa = '0.8.0-alpha.5'
```

I looked around Rust's `cargo` documentation and didn't see anything about this format.

Comment: I suggest reading and introduction to TOML first, like [this one](https://npf.io/2014/08/intro-to-toml/). The syntax in your first snippet is equivalent to having `grandpa = { package = "sc-finality-grandpa", version = "0.8.0-alpha.5" }` in the `[dependencies]` table. The Cargo documentation does not document the fundamentals of TOML.

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned in a comment, this is a combination of how TOML works combined with a [cargo feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#renaming-dependencies-in-cargotoml) that allows renaming dependencies.

Your first dependency listing renames the package to `grandpa` and is the reason that format was chosen.